# Error Handling Continuation does not execute after task encounters an exception

Tags: c++-cx

I'm a neophyte with the C++/CX tasks, and this is driving me nuts. The following code generates an exception " An invalid parameter was passed to a function that considers invalid parameters fatal". I know it successfully creates the file and gets into that task's continuation (or at least hits a breakpoint defined there), and I'm 99% sure (based on previous work) that the exception occurs due to the fact that the file is not valid XML which causes the XmlDocument::LoadFromFile method to blow up. I wanted to try to actually catch that exception, so I built an error-handling continuation as defined in several MSDN docs. (2nd Sample)

```
    TEST_METHOD(The_storage_file_must_reference_a_valid_xml_file)
    {
        auto folder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;

        auto createFileTask = 
            create_task(ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->CreateFileAsync("TestFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting))
            .then([this] (StorageFile^ file)
            {
                XmlLoadSettings^ loadSettings = ref new XmlLoadSettings();
                loadSettings->ProhibitDtd = false;
                loadSettings->ResolveExternals = false;

                auto loadXmlDocumentTask = 
                    create_task(XmlDocument::LoadFromFileAsync(file, loadSettings))
                    .then([this] (XmlDocument^ doc)
                    {
                        int x = 99;
                    });
            });
    }
```

Here is the code with the error continuation....

```
TEST_METHOD(The_storage_file_must_reference_a_valid_xml_file)
    {
        auto cut = ref new CategoryDataLoadBuilder();
        auto folder = ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder;

        auto createFileTask = 
            create_task(ApplicationData::Current->LocalFolder->CreateFileAsync("TestFile.txt", CreationCollisionOption::ReplaceExisting))
            .then([this] (StorageFile^ file)
            {
                XmlLoadSettings^ loadSettings = ref new XmlLoadSettings();
                loadSettings->ProhibitDtd = false;
                loadSettings->ResolveExternals = false;

                auto loadXmlDocumentTask = 
                    create_task(XmlDocument::LoadFromFileAsync(file, loadSettings))
                    .then([this] (task<XmlDocument^> t)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            t.get();
                        }
                        catch (COMException^ ex)
                        {
                            int x = 99;
                        }
                    });
            });
    }
```

When I try to debug this test I get an access violation in the test engine and often times it seems as if the debugger just goes off into the weeds.

Am I misunderstanding something about how the error-continuation works? Does it not work in the VS Test engine? Is there a better way to check the "real" exception that is being generated when the XML file is bad that I could explicitly check in my test?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

After some additional research and understanding, I came across this blog post: http://w8md.wordpress.com/2012/09/26/async-unit-tests-in-ccx/. Following the link within to the MSDN forum [How to use async function in unittest project by c++?](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/winappswithnativecode/thread/e51e2fbd-f5e0-45b3-8ac1-e7514b4e37d4) I saw that this is not supported in the MS Test framework. The source code presented in the article works fine. As an experiment, I extracted the code to pump events and was able to get the test to run. (Of course, I would recommend using/modifying the original author's source code.)

(As an aside, I am extremely uncomfortable answering my own question, but I'm not sure what else to do.)